# Convert emails to buttons inside contentEditable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert emails to buttons inside a contentEditable using Regex, but I'm realizing it will need too much time for me to handle cursor location, to add a delete functionality, etc. What I expect look like it:

[image]

My first idea was to use a textarea, floating in a div. That was maybe a better idea.

But... Is there some well-known open libraries to achieve it? I've seen a lot of tag libraries that can act like the tag bar on SO, but I'm searching for something that takes:

- A container
- A regex to match something
- Convert it to button
- Delete it on backspace press.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [fcbkcomplete plugin](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html)?

Comment: Totally. Didn't come accross that yet. Thank.

Comment: Finally, it's just an autocomplete widget.